# Generic Salesforce Error when creating record

Tags: apex, trigger, gack

I am creating a record of type custom object, from a long time this is working well in production.But suddenly a weird error is coming in production.

> An error has occurred while processing your request.
>
> The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!
>   Error ID: 90513625-XXXAAA(-UUUUUU)

Not really sure what makes this error, tried checking all profile level changes but everythings looks similar as previous.

Comment: Nothing we can do to help you here, I expect. Open a case if you would like additional support.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include any trigger code you might be have on that custom object? Are there any workflow rules, flows, or anything else which might run when you create it? As it stands now, theres not enough information in this question for us to help you.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks, yes i got this. But here i am checking what may be the general causes for these errors, from other posts i have got few debugging approaches but couldn't fix this issue.

Comment: You've given us nothing to work with. As @battery.cord mentions, you must give us more detail if you want any help from this community.

Comment: @battery.cord sure, let me try with the approaches given by Adrian , these are really helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've run into a gack. R&D should already be working on it or have it in their queue. If you want to work on the problem yourself, disable all triggers and flows on the object and see if the problem persists. If the gack goes away, then one of those triggers is the cause. If not, restore them all and open a case with support. Hopefully you can reproduce the gack in a sandbox environment, so you can take the above steps without incurring additional risk.

Note that Salesforce specifically calls out that the error is **not your fault** in describing what a gack is.

> ## [What Is A Gack?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html)
>
> If you’ve been around Salesforce long enough, you have probably encountered a screen that looks like this one here:
>
> [image: gack]
>
> What you are looking at is what we call a GACK. A gack is our blue screen of death, our frowny Mac icon, our “the number you have reached is no longer in service”, our “Jedediah has died of dysentery”. A gack is what happens when an error got thrown within our application and we didn’t catch it and handle it.
>
> What this means is that it’s not your fault. It’s ours. That’s why we apologize in that message. Sorry!
>
> This friendly message is the above-water portion of a huge iceberg of functionality. The numbers you see are part of an elaborate system for efficiently bringing these events to the attention of R&D. This post will help you understand that system, and how you can help us in getting you running safely. (Hint: steer away from icebergs.)